# When I try to run my war on Wildfly 8.1 I get Error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException com.myapp.myappname.api.shiro.ShiroSecuredInterceptor

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8, shiro

When I try to enable my war on Wildfly 8.1 installed on my ubuntu server I get the next error. But when I try to run my app on netbeans all its running ok. What can I do? something with modules?:

```
 10:49:49,918 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-12) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyAppName-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyAppName-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
 Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000123: Error loading com.myapp.myappname.api.shiro.ShiroSecuredInterceptor defined in <class>com.myapp.myappname.api.shiro.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</class> in vfs:/content/MyAppName-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@7
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.enablement.GlobalEnablementBuilder$ClassLoader.apply(GlobalEnablementBuilder.java:265)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.enablement.GlobalEnablementBuilder$ClassLoader.apply(GlobalEnablementBuilder.java:252)
at com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingRandomAccessList$1.transform(Lists.java:582)
at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$Builder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:281)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$ArrayBasedBuilder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:360)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$Builder.addAll(ImmutableList.java:665)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.enablement.GlobalEnablementBuilder.createModuleEnablement(GlobalEnablementBuilder.java:224)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createEnabled(BeanDeployment.java:217)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:344)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:91)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
... 3 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.myappname.api.shiro.ShiroSecuredInterceptor from [Module "deployment.MyAppName-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.enablement.GlobalEnablementBuilder$ClassLoader.apply(GlobalEnablementBuilder.java:263)
... 16 more
```

The interceptor is declared at:

WEB-INF/beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
<interceptors>
    <class>com.mycompany.myapp.api.shiro.ShiroSecuredInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
</beans>
```

Comment: Is that class in your `war` file in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory?

Comment: If the class isn't in your `WEB-INF/classes` directory or you don't have a library in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory that contains the class that would be the issue.

Comment: is at WEB-INF/beans.xml